# Integrating UrbanAirShip - Header search paths with relative path

Tags: ios, xcode, urbanairship.com

I'm trying to integrate UrbanAirShip in my application following [these steps](http://docs.urbanairship.com/build/ios.html#download-install-our-library-frameworks) .
This is what i've done:

**1)** I've Unziped the framework in the Project folder so that I have the Airship folder at the same level of other file of my project.

**2)** I've added the path ./Airship/** to my Header search Paths.
[image]
I've also tried with ../Airship/** but it doesn't work.

**3)** I try to include the right headers

```
#import "UAirship.h"
#import "UAConfig.h"
#import "UAPush.h"
```

But xcode complains... saying 'UAirship.h' file not found.

What I'm doing wrong? Have I to include the files into the project?

Comment: You need to add **../Airship/**** (you forgot a ".")

Answer (score 3):

Neither `./` or `../` worked for me in the **Header Search Paths**. I ended up using this:

```
$(PROJECT_DIR)/Airship
```

Airship folder is in same level as the project.

Answer (score 0):

You mistyped the path to add in the Header Search Paths (forgot one "**.**") :

```
./Airship/**
```

Should be :

```
../Airship/**
```

Comment: I've already tried with this path... nothing changes. I've edited my question.

Comment: @MatterGoal : If you still haven't found a solution, I suggest removing everything and going through the whole process again.

Comment: My solution at the moment was just adding the SDK to the project and not just linking it

Answer (score 0):

Did you do the following step:

**Link against the static library.**

Add the libUAirship.a file to the “Link Binary With Libraries” section in the Build Phases tab for your target.

Answer (score 0):

May not be applicable all of two years later, but I encountered a very similar problem today and solved it by using the CocoaPods version of the framework found here:

https://cocoapods.org/pods/UrbanAirship-iOS-SDK

After running pod install, I added the following paths to my Header Search Paths under target project > build settings:

[image: Header Search Path]

It seemed redundant to me to add both paths, but without the subfolders at /** the AirshipLib.h file wasn't able to locate its dependancies, and without the main folder my Bridging-Header.h file wasn't able to locate AirshipLib.h

Luckily enough I'm using some old Objective-C files from our codebase and incorporating them into a new Swift app, so I already had a Bridging-Header.h file, but if you needed to create one you can find instructions here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Finally, I added the following to my Bridging-Header.h file:

```
#import "AirshipLib.h"
```

No issues on build and everything from the framework can be easily referenced directly in my files.